# ServiceStack upgrade from V3 to V4 results in successful build but 500 at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, servicestack

I recently got licensing for ServiceStack V4 and went through the whole upgrade process from V3. Everything seems to build just fine, but for some reason I'm getting a 500 error at runtime. I have ensured the correct HttpModule referenced in the web.config due to the rename. It is currently referencing ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory. I've also checked the IIS Express logs and they aren't very helpful. It seems to just say that it failed in BeginRequest.

I can't seem to get any logging or debug information using Log4Net. I see information from RavenDB drop into the log, but nothing from ServiceStack itself. It just seems to fail silently with a 500.

All I know for sure is that if I take the ServiceStack license appSetting out I get the expected licensing exception. If I have the license in and everything it just gives me this generic 500.

This is what comes out in the log file

```
2014-06-03 15:08:58,991 [1] DEBUG Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation [(null)] - Executing query 'ServiceName:PracticeManagement' on index 'dynamic/ApiClientAuths' in 'https://ravendb.someurl.com (DB: DB);DB'
2014-06-03 15:08:59,144 [1] DEBUG Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation [(null)] - Query returned 1/1 results
2014-06-03 15:08:59,168 [1] DEBUG Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation [(null)] - Executing query 'ServiceName:PracticeManagement' on index 'dynamic/ApiClientAuths' in 'https://ravendb.someurl.com (DB: DB);DB'
2014-06-03 15:08:59,251 [1] DEBUG Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation [(null)] - Query returned 1/1 results
```

Here is the call to Configure

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
    JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

    SetConfig(new HostConfig { DebugMode = true });
    //logging
    LogManager.LogFactory = new Log4NetFactory(true);

    //Using an in-memory cache
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

    //Configure SQL database
    ConfigureSqlDb(container);
    ConfigureCrossSystemProviders(container);
    //Configure RavenDB
    this.ConfigureRavenDb("RavenDB");
    //Enable ApiKeys
    this.ConfigureApi("PracticeManagement");
    //Enable validation
    this.ConfigureValidation(typeof(GetRecipes).Assembly);
    //Enable Authentication
    ConfigureAuth(container);       
    //Enable exception management
    this.ConfigureElmah();
    //Configure CDE data
    ConfigureCdeProviders(container);
}
```

Here is some code from the web.config

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
  </httpModules>

  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Now the webserver tag

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Please post some code, and the exception stack trace. Ensure in your `Configure` method you have set `DebugMode = true`. i.e. `HostConfig = new HostConfig { DebugMode = true; }`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott. I would have posted code, but due to this being a 500 and not being able to get any good information on where to look for the failure, I'm just not sure what code to post. I have posted some from the configure call to ServiceStack and the web.cofig above. The call to logging isn't helpful at all because ServiceStack doesn't write anything in the log file, only RavenDB is at the moment.

Comment: This may be better suited to the ServiceStack support forum.  If you just purchased a license, it looks like you have [access to it](https://servicestack.net/pricing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was in the ConfigureApi method call and had to do with a Funq resolution that wasn't happening properly. I still don't know what the problem with the dependency resolution was, but I no longer have a vague HTTP 500 failure happening.